# Undefined props only in componentDidMount

Tags: react-native, react-redux

In my code below you can see my component. How it is written will cause the app to crash with the error:

> undefined is not an object (evaluation this.props.data.ID)

So in my componentDidMount that id variable is not receiving the props data.

However if i comment out that code in the componentDidMount the app will load fine and the props.data.ID will print out in View. Is there a reason why i can't access the props.data.ID in my componentDidMount?

Heres my code

```
// timeline.js
class TimelineScreen extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            posts: []
        }

    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const { id } = this.props.data.ID;

        axios.post('/api/hometimeline', { id })
        .then(res => {
            this.setState({
                posts: res.data
            });
        });
    }

    render() {
        const { data } = this.props;
        return (
            <View style={s.container}>

              {
                data
                ?
                <Text>{data.ID}</Text>
                :
                null
              }

            </View>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    const { data } = state.user;
    return {
        data
    }
}

const connectedTimelineScreen = connect(mapStateToProps)(TimelineScreen);

export default connectedTimelineScreen;
```

Answer (score 1):

The input of `mapStateToProps` is not react state, it is redux store. You shouldn't use `this.setState` in `componentDidMount`. Use redux actions and reducers to change redux store. Whenever redux store changes, it will invoke `mapStateToProps` and update your props

Answer (score 0):

```
componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props.data); // for test

    const id = this.props.data.ID;
    //OR
    const {id} = this.props.data;

    ...
}
```